# Nginx configuration filtering is not correctly filtering .exe, .txt, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, nginx

I have an nginx configuration file with the following simple configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.stage.app.net;
root /var/local/app/current/public;


location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|ttf|woff|svg)$
{
    #oboe_tracing_mode never;
    expires 1y;
}

location ~* /trackback {
  deny all;
}

location ~* \.(php|exe|src|txt)$ {
  deny all;
}

passenger_enabled on;
passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

rails_env staging;
}
```

Now what I'm trying to implement is the `trackback` and `.exe` etc. `deny all;`. This configuration only seems to be filtering out some url's while allowing others. For example, here are some urls that I am trying to filter

```
http://oh-web02.dc1.lan//download_notice.html?
filename=FileZilla_Server-0_9_31.exe
http://oh-web02.dc1.lan/llznl93573.txt

http://oh-web02.dc1.lan/p/firefox/index.php
http://oh-web02.dc1.lan/p/firefox/commits/index.exe
```

The first two urls do not filter out at all but the last two do. I've checked on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) my regex expressions and I should be filtering this correctly but for some reason it's not. Is there something incorrect about the `location` directive that I have? It should find the urls with the specified extensions. A second pair of eyes would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your location tag for `.txt` is ambiguous: it occurs in the first and third block.
   Bear in mind: The **first** regular expression location that matches the request URI is immediately selected to serve the request, so that `http://oh-web02.dc1.lan/llznl93573.txt` is never served by the `deny all` block.
2. Your second URL (`http://oh-web02.dc1.lan//download_notice.html?
   filename=FileZilla_Server-0_9_31.exe`) ends with `.html` while you were initially trying to check for the *query string*, see [**this post on serverfault**](https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string) for a workaround.